# Litespeed caches wsdl files of my webservices

Tags: caching, soap, wsdl, nusoap, litespeed

I installed Litespeed on my server,and I wrote some webservices on my website but my webservices are cached and if I change my webservices or remove them do not change anything and I see first webservices.
Also I disabled wsdl cache on my server and change wsdl cache time to zero,how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check your server settings and .htaccess for the webservice virtual host. If the server settings have cache enabled or there is a CacheEnable Public On rule in the .htaccess, all pages will be cached for that site.